# WTForms returns None only when characters that are less than 3 are entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

So I am making a webpage with Flask, and am using WTForms to get the input from the search bar.
If I search for anything that is 4 characters or more it works fine ("King", "Love", "hate" ...etc)
If I search for anything that is less than 4 ("as", "for", "the" ...etc), I get "None" from `forms.search.data`, except when I search using ISBN, then I can search with 3 characters or more, but not less.

Forms code:

```py
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search = StringField('Search', validators=[DataRequired()])
    type = SelectField('Type', choices=[('title', 'Title'), ('isbn', 'ISBN'), ('author', 'Author')])
    submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

I have tried adding `Length(min=0)` , `Length(min=1)` and `Length(min=1, max=20)`
but that didn't help.

search app.route code:

```py
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    session['searchresult'] = form.search.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.type.data == 'title':
            session['books'] = Book.bsearchtitle(title=form.search.data)
        elif form.type.data == 'isbn':
            session['books'] = Book.bsearchisbn(isbn=form.search.data)
        elif form.type.data == 'author':
            session['books'] = Book.bsearchauthor(author=form.search.data)
        return redirect(url_for('results'))
    return render_template('search.html', title='Search for books', form=form)
```

I am using `sessions['books']` to pass data to the result app.route.

result app.route code:

```py
@app.route("/results")
@login_required
def results():
    sbooks = session['books']
    searchresult = session['searchresult']
    temp = list()
    for b in sbooks:
        temp.append(json.loads(b))
    books = list()
    for t in temp:
        books.append(Book(t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4]))
    return render_template('results.html', title='Book search results', books=books, searchresult=searchresult)
```

I get the following error from Werkzeug `KeyError: 'books'` and it points to the one at the top of ``app.route("/result").

#### Extra info

If I search for "king" and get results, then I search for "the" It goes to the results page and shows the old "king" results, but it tells me that these are the results for "None", so the value stored in `searchresult` was `None`.

#### Edit 1:

So after debugging using VSCode, with a breakpoint at `return redirect(url_for('results'))` in `app.route("/search")`, the values of `form.search.data` and `session['books']` are correct.
It seems that `session['books']` is not being passed to the `app.route("/results")`. Maybe because the database response is too big? because the app works fine when I search for 4 character words.

Comment: Have you *verified with a debugger or `print()` statement* that your assumptions are correct?

Comment: Put differently: I'd be *very surprised indeed* if this was an issue with `WTForms` since it has no such limitations. It happily takes *single character* words too.

Comment: How can I verify it with a debugger? this is my first project

Comment: Depends on what your development environment looks like. If you are using `flask run` in the terminal, you can use `print()` to print values (`print("Search is set to:", repr(form.search.data))`) and those will appear in your terminal when the route is accessed.

Comment: I have packaged my app, and am running run.py from the windows cmd
If you tell me how or if you link me to somewhere I can read about the debugging procedure, I can check for its value

Comment: See [How to debug a Flask app](//stackoverflow.com/a/17322636)

Comment: ok, i used vscodes debugger and it seems that the value of the form.search.data is not ```None``` but its the string I am searching for. I guess the problem is somewhere else.  ```session['books']``` also has the response from the database stored in it, so the problem is with the redirection and reading the ```session['books']``` in the ```app.route("/results")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason for the issue is that the database query response is too big to be passed into `session['books']`.

I guess one solution would be to call the database query in the `app.route("/results")` instead of `app.route("/search")`.
If someone has any other idea please do share them.